# DropDownList using bootstrap doesn´t align properly the value selected

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a MVC Web Site and using bootstrap and jQuery to show to the user two bootstrap dropdownList in the same `<div class="form-group">` the design is as the image shows:

[image]

when the user selects the value it is showed but the align is not the correct, here is the image of the dropdownlist value selected:

[image]

As you can see the values aren't showed in the left, the first dropdownlist shows the value in the middle and the second one shows the value in the center of the input and shows the first letter of the same value at the end, could you please help me to align the value selected please.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#fddl").click(function () {
        var selText = $(this).text();
        $('#ddl1').find('#textaux').val(selText);
    });

    $("#sddl").click(function () {
        var selText2 = $(this).text();
        $('#ddl2').find('#textaux2').val(selText2);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <label>First DropDownList Selector</label>
        <div class="input-group" id="ddl1">

            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                        tabindex="-1">
                    Select
                </button>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" tabindex="-1">
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                </button>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="fddl">
                    <li><a href="#">First DropdownList option</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">First DropdownList option</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">First DropdownList option</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">First DropdownList option</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="textaux" readonly>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <label>Second DropDownList Selector</label>
        <div class="input-group" id="ddl2">

            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                        tabindex="-1">
                    Select
                </button>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" tabindex="-1">
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                </button>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="sddl">
                    <li><a href="#">Second DropDownList Option</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Second DropDownList Option</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Second DropDownList Option</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Second DropDownList Option</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Second DropDownList Option</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="textaux2" disabled>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add your `CSS` please so we might get a better idea

Comment: Hello sir, I don´t use any CSS, just the one that Bootstrap has, in addition, it I use the same dropdownlist but in different form-group the selected values is showed properly

Comment: by what i'm understanding is that you wan't your text in both selections align alike?

Comment: you can use `text-aling: center;` , `text-align: left` e.t.c for this purpose

Comment: or if you explain a bit more

Comment: yes Sir, align at the left of the text input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add to your selector to handle the `click` the `li` element.

Once your are clicking to an item of the dropdown, you should get the `click` handler on that item.

The way you are doing, you're getting the entire text of the dropdown and setting to your `input`

just change:
this `$("#fddl")` for this `$("#fddl li")`
and this `$("#sddl")` for this `$("#sddl li")`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#fddl li").click(function () {
        var selText = $(this).text();
        $('#ddl1').find('#textaux').val(selText);
    });

    $("#sddl li").click(function () {
        var selText2 = $(this).text();
        $('#ddl2').find('#textaux2').val(selText2);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <label>First DropDownList Selector</label>
        <div class="input-group" id="ddl1">

            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                        tabindex="-1">
                    Select
                </button>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" tabindex="-1">
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                </button>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="fddl">
                    <li><a href="#">First DropdownList option</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">First DropdownList option</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">First DropdownList option</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">First DropdownList option</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="textaux" readonly>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <label>Second DropDownList Selector</label>
        <div class="input-group" id="ddl2">

            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                        tabindex="-1">
                    Select
                </button>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" tabindex="-1">
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                </button>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="sddl">
                    <li><a href="#">Second DropDownList Option</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Second DropDownList Option</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Second DropDownList Option</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Second DropDownList Option</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Second DropDownList Option</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="textaux2" disabled>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```